# How to Avoid printing ascii value in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, ascii

I want to print X in the multidimensional array, but its ASCII value
gets printed repeatedly. Str is a char array. Here is the piece of code:

```
 for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(str[i][j] == "X") {
            printf("%s\t", 'X'); // ascii value gets printed
        }
        else {
            printf("%d\t", str[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What's the `str` here? Provide more information

Answer (score 2):

You seem to confuse data type `char` with a string literal. One element of a character array `str[n][n]` (assuming yours being a character array) is a value of data type `char`, not a string literal.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(str[i][j] == 'X') {
            printf("%c\t", 'X'); //format tag!
        }
        else {
            printf("%d\t", (int)str[i][j]); 
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
```

Be sure to thoroughly read `printf()` man pages. They exist to be studied!

Comment: `str[i][j]` is a character use %c in printf

Comment: You are right, but OP didn't specify that anything else than `X` should be printed as character, though...

Comment: But compiler gives a warning right! It's not a question of *if you want to print characters* . A string only holds characters.

Comment: Not all compilers give this warning, but thank you for making the point. What a string holds is `\0` terminated array of values of _data type_ `char` which `printf()` interprets according to the format tag.

Answer (score 0):

*First problem:* Assuming `str` is array of chars, in line: `str[i][j] == "X"`, you are comparing char to string literal which ends with terminal null. If you want to compare strings you can use `strcmp` function. If you however want just chars, then you should use  `str[i][j] == 'X'`

*Second problem:* When you want to print char, you should use `printf("%c\t", 'X');`